# New to SSRS (Filters)

Tags: filter, report

I am very new to SSRS.

I am in the process of building new report in Report Builder. On my initial report i had a couple of filters.

I now removed/deleted filters. When I run (F5) my report filters still still seem to appear in the run mode.

Does anyone know if there is a refresh setting that i need to look for or why changes are not being applied to updated report.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any reason why this should be the case!  What I'd suggest is what often works: save your report, exit Report Builder, go back in, open it up and try again.

Failing that, I'd assume that you've made a mistake somewhere!

Answer (score 0):

If I am correctly getting your question, then it would be the answer.

First of all, in Design tab, open your data set to edit query, remove your query of filters then press okay to save and exit from editor tab. In report data pane expand the parameters delete from here that one(s) parameter you want to remove. Press Run tab to execute your query. :)

[image: Deleting Filter]

Regards,

Muhammad Ahsan Misbah

Answer (score 0):

Remove the filters/parameters from the Report Data tab.